# Jenkins freestyle project using Gitlab API Token never clone the repository, no error, build always succeed

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I've followed this gitlab [tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html) link, to connect my jenkins server to Gitlab.

Everyting went fine, and I've :

- created a personnal access token in my GitLab profile
- created a GitLab API Token using the my GitLab access token in jenkins system configuration as stated in the tutorial
- create a freestyle jenkins job and Choose my GitLab connection from the dropdown
- checked the **Build when a change is pushed to GitLab** checkbox.
- checked the **Accepted Merge Request Events** and **Closed Merge Request Events** checkboxes
- generated a secret token from the above freestyle project
- use the freestyle jenkins project secret token to create a webhook in the GitLab project repository integration settings

Till there everything went fine.
Then I added and push code including a `jenkinsFile` to my GitLab repository, and get to the Jenkins WebUI to view the build status, but the pipeline shown green saying build success, while nothing happened, no code has been retrieved from GitLab (as shown in the attached console output screenshot), thus no `jenkinsFile` executed nor error message shown.

I tried to run the buils manually from WebUI but same result, no way to trigger my pipeline on `git push events` from GitLab

[image]

I thought may be I should select `Git` in `Source Code Management` section (I left it to `None` as the tutorial doesn't mention it) but if I choose Git as SCM I cannot select my GitLab API Token credentials, seeming like we cannot use GitLab plugin (API Token) and Git plugin for the same build project.

SO how should I proceed to be able build my jenkins project from GitLab with a jenkinsFile, using GitLab API Token?
Does the GitLab tutorial miss some useful steps?

Answer (score 5):

OK, I think I understand the issue now.
There are two sets of credentials: `GitLab API token` for access to GitLab Webhooks and a separate one for cloning the git repo during builds.

So we can't use the `GitLab API token` for cloning the repository. For this you have to use either a SSH key or a Username/Password combination. Furthermore this dropdown is part of the **git plugin** not the **gitlab plugin**.
So the **gitlab plugin** can't tell which credentials are available as credentials for this dropdown.